# Thousand separator is not applied by website module odoo9

Tags: web, odoo

I have issue in Website odoo  with product price séperator 
i change the configuration in Settings >Translations >Languages "Thousands Separator" Field 
But is not applied in Website(Look picture )
for example 200 000 > in website 200,000 
How to delete the comma

I want to display 200 000 [image]

Comment: Hello friends I found the solution________>>>

Go to language setting, set that you want a ' ' as thousand separator, and that works out of the box.

______
The only specific case that is if you don't want anything, you need to set an empty char (eg: ​) because by default, we use a comma if no symbol is given ! >>>>
**the solution**
(http://www.zupimages.net/up/17/25/mnn1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello friends I found the solution

```
>>> Go to language setting,
>>> set that you want a ' ' as thousand separator, (Put space)
>> and that works out of the box
>>>> -The only specific case that is if you don't want anything, you need to set an empty char (eg: ​) because by default, we use a comma if no symbol is given ! >>>> [the solution][1] (www.zupimages.net/up/17/25/mnn1.png) 

    tousand separator : " " ; 

  [1]: http://zupimages.net/up/17/25/mnn1.png
```